# `rightBarButtonItem` doesn't align vertically

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, ios11

The issue in my `UIViewController` is that the `rightBarButtonItem` doesn't align vertically. I will like to move the button down by 10 pixels.

[image]

```
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didPressCancelButton))
navigationItem.setRightBarButton(cancelButton, animated: true)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(12, for: .default)                  navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 12), for: .default)
```

I've also tried to move the code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` but nothing to do.

Current configuration: **iOS 11**

Comment: I suggest you can first add a UIView on rightBarButton and in that view add a button as subview , and position accordingly + apply constraints.

Comment: I achieved this my moving the searchbar little up instead ( -8 pt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the UIBarButtonItem using a custom view. This custom view will be a UIView with the actual UIButton (as a subview) placed x pixels from the top (x=the number of pixels you want to move it down).

Here is an example of how to go about doing that:

```
var button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setTitle("Settings", for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 179.0 / 255.0, green: 40.0 / 255.0, blue: 18.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 20)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.yourCustomSelectorHere), for: .touchUpInside)

var backButtonView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 63, height: 33))
    backButtonView.bounds = backButtonView.bounds.offsetBy(dx: -14, dy: -7)
    backButtonView.addSubview(button)
    var barBtnItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButtonView)
    navigationItem?.rightBarButtonItem = barBtnItem
```

You will just need to configure the code slightly to be in the correct position within your view.

Comment: thanks I will try tomorrow. Sad that I need to change that... I managed to vertically align a leftBarButtonItem in another view controller (with the same code in my question), but it seems not working for rightBarButtonItems.

Comment: iOS 11 is a playground of issues. Please let me know if you don’t get it working and I can look into it a bit more. Cheers!

Comment: Your solution work. I'm wondering if it's gonna be placed correctly on iOS10 (I don't have a way to check that at the moment).